# Importing asynchronous modules to driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-modules

I have a program with a few modules with asynchronous actions contained inside, connecting to my database and connecting to an external server, to name a couple. In my driver file for the whole program, I am importing these modules, but am having difficulty figuring out how to have them complete one after another. i.e. Connects to external server, subsequently connects to my database, and then once those are done, logs to the console that they have both been completed.

Previously, I tried wrapping all the modules in promises, and then in the driver doing a `Promise.all()` on all of them. Although it worked successfully, I figure this is a "hacky" way of achieving my end goal, and would like to know if there are any better ways to go about doing this.

For reference, in module 1:

```
function connectToServer(() => {
     server.connect()
     .then(() => {
       console.log('connected to server');
     });
});
```

In module 2:

```
function connectToDatabase(() => {
    database.connect()
    .then(() => {
       console.log('connected to database');
    });
});
```

And in the driver:

```
require server connection module
require database connection module
console.log('both are done');
```

With output:

```
connected to server
connected to database
both are done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if clarity related to my question is needed, I can provide.

Comment: Can you show the actual code, not pseudo code like `require server connection module` please? Also `function connectToDatabase(() => {…})` is a syntax error

Comment: Why do you care that it connects to the database *after* it finished connecting to the server? Notice that when you do, `Promise.all` doesn't make sense, you need a promise chain.

Comment: @Bergi Not sure the reason I care for the order is pertinent, just know that it does indeed matter. Similarly, a ```Promise.all``` approach was my prior solution, which did in fact work as desired after wrapping all modules in a promise. As for the syntax error, as you said, I was writing in pseudocode, I was not paying attention to syntax as the presented code was just to convey what the modules could potentially look like, as I do not see why the lengthy code is particularly necessary to aiding in the creation of an answer when the general idea is readily presented.

Comment: A general answer would be that the general approach is generally fine, not hacky :-) But if you need help with specific difficulties, you need to share your actual code. It's not even quite clear whether your modules create and export a promise, or a function that creates and returns a promise.

Comment: @Bergi As stated before, what I believed to be the hacky way of doing things (that you have since said is not) was that each module created and exported a promise in order to achieve my goal. However, the base of the module is simply a function that creates and returns a promise.

Comment: If you need the connections to be made in order, then the modules should not rely on being loaded in the right order. Either have them export functions, then call these functions in the right order in your entrypoint script, or make the dependency explicit by having module 2 import module 1 and waiting for its promise before making its own connection.

Comment: @Bergi Alright, that sounds like a much better approach, thank you for your time.